# how can I generate lat long fields into geo point in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, mapping, elasticsearch-painless, geopoints

I've ingested CSV data via pgsync from postgres RDS to elasticsearch.my index contains "lat" and "lng"

```
"lat" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "lng" : {
      "type" : "float"
```

How would I convert this into an acceptable geopoint format so that I can map it in Kibana?

I already add this mapping:

````
    ``` PUT /my-index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "location": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
  }
}```
````

but when I'm trying to generate new coordinate field via:

````
``` POST your_index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.location = ctx._source.lat, ctx._source.lon",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}```





I am unable and getting this error

'''
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "compile error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "... ocation = ctx._source.lat, ctx._source.lng",
          "                             ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "ctx._source.location = ctx._source.lat, ctx._source.lng",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "position" : {
          "offset" : 38,
          "start" : 13,
          "end" : 55
        }
      }
'''
````

Is there any suggestion or correction for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start! Your script needs to look like this

```
POST your_index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.location = ['lat': ctx._source.lat, 'lon': ctx._source.lng]",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": { 
            "field": "lat"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": { 
            "field": "lng"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Val, I ran this one but getting this error:  failures" : [
    {
      "index" : "restaurant_location10",
      "id" : "210641",
      "cause" : {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse field [location] of type [geo_point]",
        "caused_by" : {
          "type" : "parse_exception",
          "reason" : "field must be either [lat], [lon], [geohash], [coordinates] or [type]"
        }
      },
      "status" : 400.

Comment: Maybe one of your document doesn't have the `lat` and/or `lng` field. I've updated my answer to prevent that